# How to solve two simultaneous equations provided that one of the variables cannot take values of integer multiples of Pi?

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve these two simultaneous equations for $E_p(k)$ provided that $p\neq \pm n\pi$, where $n$ is an integer:

```
3 K*d^2 + Sqrt[C1^2 + 4*C2^2*Cos[k/2]^2 + 4*C1*C2*Cos[k/2]*Cos[p]]==Ep;
C1*Sin[p*n] + 2*C2*Cos[k/2]*Sin[p*(n + 1)]==0;
```

I've tried declaring $p\neq \pm n\pi$ within an NSolve in place of inequalities and I've tried deleting the undesired $p$ values posthumously using DeleteCases, both to no avail.
Here are the constants used too:

```
n = 3;
t = 2.5;
a = 6.31;
K = 49.7;
d = 0.1;
C1 = -t - 2*a*d;
C2 = -t + a*d;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From the docs of `NSolve`: "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations." It is basically a numerical version of `Solve`, trying to find all possible solutions to (sets of) polynomial equations. Of course it can handle some other types of equations, but few general cases. Try with `FindInstance` or `FindRoot` instead, or just to be sure, `Solve` but with exact coefficients (497/10 instead of 49.7 etc.)

Comment: Note though that if you demand the `Sqrt` in the fist equation to be real, then you can move `3 K*d^2` to the RHS, square both sides, and isolate `Cos[p]`...

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy reply! I tried all the things you've suggested and solutions are indeed missing when it comes to plotting $E_{\pm}(k)$. What I don't understand is that when I set $d=0$ and $t=1$ I obtain the required results as long as I specify that $p\neq0$, $p\neq-\pi$ and $p\neq\pi$. So surely then I can extend it to having more coefficients (as in this case)? Why would that suddenly make it unsolvable?

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
Simplify[Reduce[{3 K*d^2+Sqrt[C1^2+4*C2^2*Cos[k/2]^2+4*C1*C2*Cos[k/2]*Cos[p]]==Ep, 
C1*Sin[p*n]+2*C2*Cos[k/2]*Sin[p*(n+1)]==0, Sin[n p]!=0, Sin[p*(n+1)]!=0,
n \[Element] Integers}, {Ep, k}] //.
{n->3, t->2.5, a->6.31, K->49.7, d->0.1, C1-> -t-2*a*d, C2-> -t+a*d},
Sin[3 p]!=0 && Sin[4 p]!=0]
```

which gives you

```
(* C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
Ep == 1.491+1.881 Sqrt[1/(Cos[p]+Cos[3 p])^2] &&
(k==4 \[Pi] C[1]+2 ArcCos[-1.00642 Csc[4 p] Sin[3 p]] || 
 k==4 \[Pi] C[1]-2 ArcCos[-1.00642 Csc[4 p] Sin[3 p]])
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! I can't believe I didn't think of using $sin[p n]\neq0$ instead of $p\neq0$... I'm looking for $E$ as a function of $k$ and not of $p$, but I tried using this with `{Ep,p}` instead but there were issues. Taking some of what you've done into account I wrote this:
`m \[Element] Integers;
rootsp = NSolve[{Fp[c, p] == Ep, F[c, p] == 0, Sin[p*m] != 0, 
    Sin[p*(m + 1)] != 0}, {Ep, p}];
p1 = Plot[Ep /. rootsp, {c, -Pi, Pi}];` It didn't work and the undesired values were still there! I simply don't understand why it's ignoring the inequations bit...